# How to insert elements with attributes to an XML file using XmlStarlet?

Tags: xml, shell, xpath, xmlstarlet

### Source XML

```
<xml>
    <block>
        <el name="a">92346</el>
        <el name="b">lorem</el>
    </block>
    <block>
        <el name="a">89753</el>
        <el name="b">ipsum</el>
    </block>
</xml>
```

### Object

I would like to insert an `<el name="c">0</el>` element in every `<block>` with a Linux shell script:

```
<xml>
    <block>
        <el name="a">92346</el>
        <el name="b">lorem</el>
        <el name="c">0</el>
    </block>
    <block>
        <el name="a">89753</el>
        <el name="b">ipsum</el>
        <el name="c">0</el>
    </block>
</xml>
```

I can append the elements using XmlStarlet:

```
xmlstarlet ed -a '/xml/block/el[@name="b"]' \
              --type 'elem' -n 'el' -v 0
```

### Questions

1. What is the XPath expression that selects every `<el>` element which
   doesn't have a `name` attribute?
2. Can I append the elements and insert the attributes with a single
   [`xml ed`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s03.html) command?

Answer (score 10):

### Answers

1. `/xml/block/el[not(@name)]`
2. As stated in an [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5966479/868052):

> You can't insert an element with an attribute directly but since
>   every edit operation is performed in sequence, you can insert an
>   element and then add an attribute.

### The command

```
xmlstarlet ed -a '/xml/block/el[@name="b"]' \
              -t 'elem' -n 'el' -v 0 \
              -i '/xml/block/el[not(@name)]' \
              -t 'attr' -n 'name' -v 'c'
```