# Insert 1000+ nodes and attributes with XMLStarlet - Running Slow

Tags: xml, bash, shell, unix, xmlstarlet

This is a matter of efficiency rather than troubleshooting. I have the following code snippet:

```
# The -R flag restores malformed XML
xmlstarlet -q fo -R <<<"$xml_content" | \
    # Delete xml_data
    xmlstarlet ed -d "$xml_data" | \
    # Delete index
    xmlstarlet ed -d "$xml_index" | \
    # Delete specific objects
    xmlstarlet ed -d "$xml_nodes/objects" | \
    # Append new node
    xmlstarlet ed -s "$xml_nodes" -t elem -n subnode -v "Hello World" | \
        # Add x attribute to node
        xmlstarlet ed -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n x -v "0" | \
        # Add y attribute to node
        xmlstarlet ed -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n y -v "0" | \
        # Add z attribute to node
        xmlstarlet ed -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n z -v "1" \
            > "$output_file"
```

- The variable `$xml_content` contains the xml tree of contents and
  nodes parsed from a file with size 472.6 MB using the `cat` command.
- The variable `$output_file` as its name indicates, contains the path 
  to the output file.
- The rest of the variables simply contain the according XPaths I want to edit.

According to this brief [article](https://www.technomancy.org/xml/add-a-subnode-command-line-xmlstarlet/) which helped come up with this code, it indicates that:

> This is a bit ineffeciant since the xml file is parsed and written twice.

In my case, it is parsed and written more than twice (eventually in a `loop` over 1000 times).

So, taking the above script, the execution time alone of that short fragment is 4 mins and 7 secs.

Assuming the excessive, repetitive and perhaps inefficient piping together with the file size is why the code runs slow, the more subnodes I ultimately insert/delete will eventually cause it to execute even slower.

I apologise in advance if I might sound monotonous by reiterating myself or by bringing out an old and probably already answered topic, however, I'm really keen to understand how `xmlstarlet` works in detail with large XML documents.

---

**UPDATE**

As claimed by @Cyrus in his prior answer:

> Those two xmlstarlets should do the job:
>
> ```
> xmlstarlet -q fo -R <<<"$xml_content" |\
>   xmlstarlet ed \
>     -d "$xml_data" \
>     -d "$xml_index" \
>     -d "$xml_nodes/objects" \
>     -s "$xml_nodes" -t elem -n subnode -v "Hello World" \
>     -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n x -v "0" \
>     -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n y -v "0" \
>     -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n z -v "1" > "$output_file"
> ```

This produced the following errors:

- `-:691.84: Attribute x redefined`
- `-:691.84: Attribute z redefined`
- `-:495981.9: xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node: out of memory`
- `-:495981.9: Extra content at the end of the document`

I honestly don't know how these errors where produced because I changed the code too often testing various scenarios and potential alternatives, however, this is what did the trick for me:

```
xmlstarlet ed --omit-decl -L \
    -d "$xml_data" \
    -d "$xml_index" \
    -d "$xml_nodes/objects" \
    -s "$xml_nodes" -t elem -n subnode -v "Hello World" \
    "$temp_xml_file"

xmlstarlet ed --omit-decl -L \
    -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n x -v "0" \
    -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n y -v "0" \
    -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n z -v "1" \
    "$temp_xml_file"
```

Regarding the actual `data` that is inserted, this is what I have at the beginning:

```
...
<node>
    <subnode>A</subnode>
    <subnode>B</subnode>
    <objects>1</objects>
    <objects>2</objects>
    <objects>3</objects>
    ...
</node>
...
```

Executing the above (split) code gives me what I want:

```
...
<node>
    <subnode>A</subnode>
    <subnode>B</subnode>
    <subnode x="0" y="0" z="1">Hello World</subnode>
</node>
...
```

By splitting them, `xmlstarlet` is able to insert the `attributes` into the newly created node, else it will add them to the `last()` instance of the selected Xpath before the `--subnode` is even created. To some extent this is still inefficient, nevertheless, the code runs in less than a minute now.

The following code,

```
xmlstarlet ed --omit-decl -L \
    -d "$xml_data" \
    -d "$xml_index" \
    -d "$xml_nodes/objects" \
    -s "$xml_nodes" -t elem -n subnode -v "Hello World" \
    -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n x -v "0" \
    -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n y -v "0" \
    -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n z -v "1" \
    "$temp_xml_file"
```

However, gives me this:

```
...
<node>
    <subnode>A</subnode>
    <subnode x="0" y="0" z="1">B</subnode>
    <subnode>Hello World</subnode>
</node>
...
```

By joining the `xmlstarlets` into one like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962889/bash-insert-subnode-to-xml-file) also answered by @Cyrus, it somehow first adds the `attributes` and then creates the `--subnode` where the `innerText` is `Hello World`.

- Can anyone explain why this strange behaviour is happening??

This is another [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080050/how-to-insert-elements-with-attributes-to-an-xml-file-using-xmlstarlet/#answer-19080051) which states that "**every edit operation is performed in sequence**"

The above article explains exactly what I'm looking for, yet I cannot manage to make it work all in one `xmlstarlet ed \`. Alternatively, I tried:

- Replacing `($xml_nodes)[last()]` with `$xml_nodes[text() = 'Hello World']`
- Using `$prev` (or `$xstar:prev`) as the argument to `-i` like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954168/how-to-insert-a-new-element-under-another-with-xmlstarlet/#answer-29958992). [[Examples]](https://sourceforge.net/p/xmlstar/code/ci/master/tree/examples/)
- The [temporary element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954168/how-to-insert-a-new-element-under-another-with-xmlstarlet/#answer-9172796) trick via `-r` to rename the temp node after the `attr` are added

All of the above insert the `--subnode` but leave the new element without `attributes`.

**Note**: I run XMLStarlet 1.6.1 on OS X El Capitan v 10.11.3

---

**BONUS**

As I mentioned in the beginning I wish to use a `loop` like something along these lines:

```
list="$(tr -d '\r' < $names)"

for name in $list; do
    xmlstarlet ed --omit-decl -L \
    -d "$xml_data" \
    -d "$xml_index" \
    -d "$xml_nodes/objects" \
    -s "$xml_nodes" -t elem -n subnode -v "$name" \
    -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n x -v "0" \
    -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n y -v "0" \
    -i "($xml_nodes)[last()]" -t attr -n z -v "1" \
    "$temp_xml_file"
done
```

The `$list` contains over a thousand different names which need to be added with their respective `attributes`. The `--value` of each attribute may vary with every `loop` as well. Given the above model:

- What is the fastest and most accurate version of such `loop` given that the attributes are added correctly to the corresponding node?
- Would it be faster to create the list of nodes in an external txt file and later add those xml elements (inside the txt file) **into**  another XML file. If yes, how? Perhaps with `sed` or `grep`?

Regarding the last question, I refer to something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234681/adding-xml-element-in-xml-file-using-sed-command-in-shell-script#answer-23235535). The node where the `xml` from the txt should be added has to be specific, e.g. selectable by XPath at least because I want to edit certain nodes only.

**Note**: The above model is just an example. The actual `loop` will add 26 `--subnodes` for each `loop` and 3 or 4 `attr` for each `--subnode`.  Thats why it's important for `xmlstarlet` to add the `attr` properly and not to some other element. They have to be added in order.

Comment: I updated my question with example input/output just like you suggested @Cyrus

Answer (score 2):

Why not use parallel (or sem) so that you can parallelise the job over the number of cores available on the machine?
The code I use is parsing an array with 2 variables, that I export in local just to make sure processes are isolated.

```
for array in "${listofarrays[@]}"; do
    local var1;local var2
    IFS=, read var1 var2 <<< $array
    sem -j +0
    <code goes here>
done
sem --wait
```

Comment: Thanks @user1747036 but I would also  like to know how I can add `attr` correctly. Do you have any suggestions? I actually like really much your idea of reading the array.  Could you extend a little on what the input and output would look like?

Comment: Btw I cam across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33653844/xmlstarlet-sel-on-large-file), which says that the files are read into memory. Wouldn't parallelising xmlstarlets eat up all my memory? Just use xmlstarlet to import an entire list of nodes once (including attr) like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234681/adding-xml-element-in-xml-file-using-sed-command-in-shell-script#answer-23235535) sounds suitable, but how I can I select the correct node in order to add the elements as subnodes?

Comment: Something like: `$ sed '/<\/Students>/{ r add.txt a \</Students> d }' file` but replacing `</Students>` with the correct (and probably unique) node (using XPath?)

Answer (score 1):

[unbuffer](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/unbuffer.1.html) might help

unbuffer from the [expect](https://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/) package

to build a pipe from two commands a, z

```
unbuffer a | z
```

to build a pipe from three (or more) commands a, b, z
add the -p option inside the pipe

```
unbuffer a | unbuffer -p b | z
```

source: stolen from [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)