# xmlstarlet add undiscriminated rows

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I have the following XML file:

I try to add the following

```
<functions loglevel="error">
<function spreadsheet_function="GETTPOS"/>
<function spreadsheet_function="GETLPOS"/>
</functions>
```

I executed the following:

```
xmlstarlet ed -s "/_:php_macro_engine_config" -t elem -n "functions" -v "" -i "/_:php_macro_engine_config/functions" -t attr -n loglevel -v error
-s "/_:php_macro_engine_config/functions" -t elem -n "function" -i "/_:php_macro_engine_config/functions/function" -t attr -n spreadsheet_function -v GETTPOS
-s "/_:php_macro_engine_config/functions" -t elem -n "function" -i "/_:php_macro_engine_config/functions/function" -t attr -n spreadsheet_function -v GETLPOS 
macro_engine_config.xml
```

it creates the following:

```
<function spreadsheet_function="GETTPOS" spreadsheet_function="GETLPOS"/>
<function spreadsheet_function="GETLPOS"/>
```

how can I differentiate both in the xmlstarlet parameters?

Comment: please edit to show your "raw" input file (OR correct your explanation ;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9172796/319698