# Xmlstarlet select nodes and adding subnodes

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to automate adding new subnodes to nexus-core-feature-3.16.1-02.xml Because we are using some plugins for work that not come with "box" solution. 
The main point that when new version of the nexus-container releases I have a bash-script that runs new test-container version and copies the new default-xml file to a proper folder.
The next step is to redact this file and add some new features to make plug-in work. When this done old container stops, new xml-replace old one and I'm starting a docker-container with mapped nexus-data and default-xml.
For proper work of this plug-in I need to add some changes to the default-xml file. And I want to use xmlstarlet for that.
Add this to "nexus-core-feature" section:

```
<feature version="1.0.9" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-apt</feature>
  </feature>
```

And this to the end of the file xml-file

```
<feature name="nexus-repository-apt" description="net.staticsnow:nexus-repository-apt" version="1.0.10">
     <details>net.staticsnow:nexus-repository-apt</details>
     <bundle>mvn:net.staticsnow/nexus-repository-apt/1.0.10</bundle>
     <bundle>mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.18</bundle>
     <bundle>mvn:org.tukaani/xz/1.8</bundle>
</feature>
</features>
```

So I was google and SO for a while but I'm still stuck.
For example this case: [How to insert a new element under another with xmlstarlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954168/how-to-insert-a-new-element-under-another-with-xmlstarlet)

It seems pretty straightforward to do something similar and I tried this:

```
xmlstarlet ed -s /features/feature/feature -t elem -n featureTMP -v "nexus-apt-repositroy" \
    -i //featureTMP -t attr -n "version" -v "1.0.9" \
    -i //featureTMP P -t attr -n "prerequisite" -v "false" \
    -i //featureTMP -t attr -n "dependency" -v "false" \
    -r //featureTMP -v feature nexus-core-feature-3.16.1-02-features.xml
```

I suspect that my mistake was (and is) in nodes path.

Next step was to examine nodes

`xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/" nexus-core-feature-3.16.1-02-features.xml`

Output was the whole xml-file and it seems to be fine

```
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0" name="nexus-core-feature">
    <feature name="nexus-core-feature" description="org.sonatype.nexus.assemblies:nexus-core-feature" version="3.16.1.02">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.assemblies:nexus-core-feature</details>
        <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-audit-plugin</feature>
        <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-blobstore-tasks</feature>
        <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-ssl-plugin</feature>
        <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-coreui-plugin</feature>
        <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-httpbridge</feature>
...
```

But when I try to get into the node the result is always empty:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/features" nexus-core-feature-3.16.1-02-features.xml
```

With attribute selector it's still empty:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/features/feature[@name="nexus-core-feature"]" nexus-core-feature-3.16.1-02-features.xml
```

Tried to chek this in XPath-online tester and inside of tester everything OK.

Next I use more simple example in this article: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386965/insert-custom-xml-tag-into-a-xml-file-in-a-bash-script

and tried to navigate throught example file that was in arctilce and it seems to be fine.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/server-groups" file.xml
```

output:

```
<server-groups>
  <server-group name="main-server-group" profile="full">
    <jvm name="default">
      <heap size="64m" max-size="512m"/>
      <jvm-options>
        <option value="somevalue"/>
      </jvm-options>
    </jvm>
    <socket-binding-group ref="full-sockets"/>
  </server-group>
</server-groups>
```

Next step

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/server-groups/server-group/jvm" file.xml
```

output:

```
<jvm name="default">
      <heap size="64m" max-size="512m"/>
      <jvm-options>
        <option value="somevalue"/>
      </jvm-options>
    </jvm>
```

And it's very confusing for me... Why the same approach doesn't work with nexus-xml file? More complex\strange structure? Will be glad for any advise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the same approach doesn't work with nexus-xml file?

It's because your nexus XML file is in a default namespace (`http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0`).

If you're using xmlstarlet version 1.0.5 or later, you can use `_:` in your XPath to match any namespace. Otherwise you'll have to bind the namespace to a prefix with `-N`. [See here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139530992) for more info.

Here's an updated example of your first attempt:

```
xmlstarlet ed -s /_:features/_:feature -t elem -n featureTMP -v "nexus-repository-apt" \
    -i //featureTMP -t attr -n "version" -v "1.0.9" \
    -i //featureTMP -t attr -n "prerequisite" -v "false" \
    -i //featureTMP -t attr -n "dependency" -v "false" \
    -r //featureTMP -v feature nexus-core-feature-3.16.1-02-features.xml
```

Here's the alternative approach of using `-N`...

```
xmlstarlet ed -N f="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0" -s /f:features/f:feature -t elem -n featureTMP -v "nexus-repository-apt" \
    -i //featureTMP -t attr -n "version" -v "1.0.9" \
    -i //featureTMP -t attr -n "prerequisite" -v "false" \
    -i //featureTMP -t attr -n "dependency" -v "false" \
    -r //featureTMP -v feature nexus-core-feature-3.16.1-02-features.xml
```

Both of these produce the following output:

```xml
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0" name="nexus-core-feature">
  <feature name="nexus-core-feature" description="org.sonatype.nexus.assemblies:nexus-core-feature" version="3.16.1.02">
    <details>org.sonatype.nexus.assemblies:nexus-core-feature</details>
    <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-audit-plugin</feature>
    <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-blobstore-tasks</feature>
    <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-ssl-plugin</feature>
    <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-coreui-plugin</feature>
    <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-httpbridge</feature>
    <feature version="1.0.9" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-apt</feature>
  </feature>
</features>
```

Adding your second `feature` can be done the same way, but you could also simplify the whole thing by using XSLT in xmlstarlet with the [tr command](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139602800). (It's simpler in my opinion anyway.)

**XSLT** (test.xsl)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:f="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0"
  xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="f">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="f:features">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <feature name="nexus-repository-apt" description="net.staticsnow:nexus-repository-apt" version="1.0.10">
        <details>net.staticsnow:nexus-repository-apt</details>
        <bundle>mvn:net.staticsnow/nexus-repository-apt/1.0.10</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.18</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.tukaani/xz/1.8</bundle>
      </feature>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="f:feature[@name='nexus-core-feature']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <feature version="1.0.9" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-apt</feature>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**xmlstarlet command**

```
xmlstarlet tr test.xsl nexus-core-feature-3.16.1-02-features.xml
```

**Output**

```xml
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0" name="nexus-core-feature">
  <feature name="nexus-core-feature" description="org.sonatype.nexus.assemblies:nexus-core-feature" version="3.16.1.02">
    <details>org.sonatype.nexus.assemblies:nexus-core-feature</details>
    <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-audit-plugin</feature>
    <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-blobstore-tasks</feature>
    <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-ssl-plugin</feature>
    <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-coreui-plugin</feature>
    <feature version="3.16.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-httpbridge</feature>
    <feature version="1.0.9" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-apt</feature>
  </feature>
  <feature name="nexus-repository-apt" description="net.staticsnow:nexus-repository-apt" version="1.0.10">
    <details>net.staticsnow:nexus-repository-apt</details>
    <bundle>mvn:net.staticsnow/nexus-repository-apt/1.0.10</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.18</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.tukaani/xz/1.8</bundle>
  </feature>
</features>
```

Comment: Thanks for a great anwser Daniel! It seems to be workable solution for me but still need to redact a little for my case :)

Comment: @АфанасьевДмитрий - Glad I could help!