# Adding the xml tag after the specified string using SED

Tags: sed

Planning to add the below content after the closing tab  into the main.xml

Keeping the below xml tag information into the ADD.txt file.

```
<student>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <id>0111</id>
     -----
</student>
```

Executing the following command: The information is adding above the tag </class>,
Planning to add the ADD.txt content after the tag </class>

sed -i '/</class>/e cat ADD.txt' main.xml

Comment: `sed -i '/<\/class>/r ADD.txt' main.xml` ?

Comment: content is not adding  before or after the xml tag </class> once we use "r"

Comment: working fine now - we have to give space between "/ and r" 
sed -i '/<\/class>/ r ADD.txt' main.xml

Comment: Use a real XML parser such as [xml-starlet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5954168/290085) to parse XML, not regex.  Why?  See [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)