# SED command for add the content before the xml tag

Tags: xml, sed

```
sed -i '/<\/example-tag>/ r data.txt' sample.xml
```

I can able to add the content from  data.txt AFTER the xml tag `</example-tag`> into the file sample.xml using the above sed command.

I am looking the option how we can add the content BEFORE xml tag `</example-tag>`

Comment: Please show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Moreover, to parse HTML, use a HTML parser like `xmlstarlet`, I will show you if you edit your post with your sample input and expected output

Comment: And show us what is `sample.xml`, not only `data.txt`

Comment: Use a real XML parser such as [xml-starlet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5954168/290085) to parse XML, not regex.  Why?  See [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)