# maven: Is it possible to override location of local repository via the use of command line option or env variable?

Tags: maven, maven-2

Currently we specify the location of local repository in the settings.xml. Is it possible to override this setting via command line or env variable, such that I can use an alternative location sometimes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying Maven's local repository location as a CLI parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823462/specifying-mavens-local-repository-location-as-a-cli-parameter)

Comment: It didn't occur to me why this would be useful until now - if you're working on several branches (a release branch, a trunk branch) and the source tree is complex, trying to get compilation to work can be a nightmare if you're just using `1.0-SNAPSHOT` as your version. Having separate .m2 repos circumvents a lot of this.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You would need to specify the `maven.repo.local` parameter to do this.

```
mvn package -Dmaven.repo.local=/alternate/repo/location
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71030/can-i-add-maven-repositories-in-the-command-line) is a related SO question.

Comment: The local repository must be an absolute path, https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html.

Comment: @luka5z: Thanks for the important doc ref, but I can say with experience the path can be relative for `--define maven.repo.local=local/repo/here`.  Maybe absolute paths are only required for `settings.xml`?

Comment: @Raghuram: flawless answer

Answer (score 19):

Use the localRepository setting in your settings.xml file.  Example:

```
<settings>
  <localRepository>/repo</localRepository>
  ...
</settings>
```

See [here](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for more info.

You can also set the repository via the command line using "-Dmaven.repo.local="  such as:

```
mvn -U clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=C:\tmp
```

Comment: We have already done it in our settings.xml. I want to override it when I invoke maven in a shell

Comment: If maven is using that settings.xml, even when you invoke it from a shell, it should pick up that setting.  It's very common for windows users to need to set that due to spaces in their home directory "c:\documents and settings\blah"

Comment: Just ran a test using " <localRepository>/Users/michael/Desktop/repository</localRepository>
" in my settings.xml file.  And now when I build anything from command line (or ide) it's putting the artifacts there.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question.  The answer above is correct.  You can use the "-Dmaven.repo.local=/alternate/repo/location" option on the commands.