# Disable Maven local repository for a project

Tags: maven

I want to build a project without referring to my local Maven repo at all, but on the other hand I don't want it to be pruned, as other projects on my disk use it.

How can I disable local repo for some particular project?

Ideally, I'd like to create new repo in `target` directory and then automatically clean it after build.

Question [maven: Is it possible to override location of local repository via the use of command line option or env variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123004/maven-is-it-possible-to-override-location-of-local-repository-via-the-use-of-co) explains only how to change location of local repo for some particular build or in settings. I'm interested in permanent solution in POM.

Comment: What do you mean "disable local repo"? Where would Maven get the dependencies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maven: Is it possible to override location of local repository via the use of command line option or env variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123004/maven-is-it-possible-to-override-location-of-local-repository-via-the-use-of-co), by setting the location to a location like `/tmp` you can effectifly have a one shot or local-less build for the project.

Comment: @Tunaki please see my edit

Comment: Okay, then see the linked question yes. Just override the `maven.repo.local` property to point to the target folder then.

Comment: @Tunaki thanks. Can I also specify `maven.repo.local` in POM instead of command line or settings?

Comment: Not sure, never tried that. I don't see why it wouldn't work yes.