# Installing to another local repo in Maven [JAVA]

Tags: java, maven

Short question:

Is there a way to install compiled jar files to another local repo other than the local repo of external dependencies?

Long question:

I want to compile my project using `mvn clean install`. 
Since the project uses some external dependencies, but maven will download those dependencies into my local repo.

This is good, but what I do not want is having the compiled jar files of my project also stored there, mixing with the others.

I want to find a way to keep all external dependencies in one local repo (e.g. C:\Repo) and then all my project jars are found in another local repo (e.g. D:\Repo) after compilation.

Comment: I don't think you can, one instance of Maven will use one local repository directory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451973/separate-local-download-and-install-repositories-using-maven

Comment: The install plugin accepts `-DlocalRepositoryPath` which would override the used repository. I imagine this is as close as you come, but it doesn't seem to help you all the way.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why would you like to separate them? What is your problem there? If you want to just compile/test your project you can simply achieve that by using `mvn clean package` or if you like to include integration tests `mvn clean verify` so nothing is installed into the local cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want double `<localrepository>`, what is not possible for a single maven project.

1. If you use settings you will add a new [`<localrepository>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html) tag, you cannot add 2 `<localrepository>` tags.
2. If you configure maven in your IDE i.e: Eclipse, you will have only a single text box to introduce a single localrepository location.

---

From [DOCUMENTATION](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

## Settings Details

**Simple Values**

> Half of the top-level settings elements are simple values, representing a range of values which describe elements of the build system that are active full-time.
>
> [...]
>
> **localRepository:** This value is the path of this build system’s local repository. The default value is `${user.home}/.m2/repository`. [...]

So, `localRepository` is a simple value, detailed in DTD (haven't found, someone?) of `settings.xml`, then does not matter how you configure maven, at the end, `settings.xml` file will be created somehow **AND** won't allow 2  `localrepository` tags.

Comment: I had a brainfart... I wonder if you could hack it with a symbolic link (which even modern Windows partitions support).

Comment: @Gimby you know what DTD is? no hack for xml i guess, only one location will be allowed AFAIK

Comment: Thanks. How about some hacky way? Like doing two passes? I am thinking if there is a way to stop maven from installing my project files to my local repo, then I can first compile normally (without storing my project files). Second pass set my local repo as the remote repo using file:// and change my local repo to another folder, allowing maven to install my project files this time.

Comment: @user1589188 Maven will then download and install all dependencies in the local repo of the second pass, not only your project artifacts.

Comment: @user1589188 They'd just see a demand from one person without any explanation at all.