# Maven make project offline and repository in project folder

Tags: maven

I try to make my Project offline and build the project with an in-project-repo. So the ~/.m2/ directory is empty at the beginning. I added the following into my poms:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project</id>
        <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>project</id>
        <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Then I deleted everything in my .m2 folder and build my project with internet with the option 
`-dependency:go-offline`
This works. Then I copy everything out of the .m2/repository directory into my lib directory in my project and delete the content in .m2/repository. Now I disconnect from the internet and try to build my project with the option -o. This dont work and I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: The repository system is offline but the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 is not available in the local repository. -> [Help 1]
```

In my lib folder(in-project-repo) exist this plugin and all the other plugins. 
I have some sources who are not availbable in the internet. I copyed them to my lib folder(in-project-repo) and they get copyed into the local m2 repository when I build my project. So I guess my in-project-repo is working. I don't understand this.
If I let the content int the  ~/.m2 folder I can build my project without internet.

I hope someone can help me!

Kindly Regards

EDIT: I made it work with the option:

```
-Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/project/lib clean package -X -o
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are 2 ways to override the location of the local repo. In the settings.xml or from the command line. [maven: Is it possible to override location of local repository via the use of command line option or env variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123004/maven-is-it-possible-to-override-location-of-local-repository-via-the-use-of-co)