# Maven - alternative .m2 directory

Tags: maven

How do I globally change the location of maven's `.m2` directory?

Maven uses `${user.home}/.m2` for it's settings, repository cache, etc.

I know that I can:

- point to a different dir for the repository cache (by changing the `localRepository` attribute in my global config file), but not for anything else (`settings.xml`, for instance).
- Use the `-s` CLI option, but I'd have to do that every time I use maven.

But ideally, I'd like a global solution.  Intuitively that should be possible..

I'd like to do this because my company sets my ${user.home} to a shared drive which is prone to network issues.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable to set the location of your repository. Set it in your shell startup, and you don't have to put it on the command line every time.

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/repository"
```

You said you wanted to change the `.m2` for the `settings.xml` file as well as the `repository` directory. You want to set the `M2_HOME` environment variable. The [Maven settings documentation](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) says that it controls where Maven looks for `settings.xml`. From there, you can control the repository location, etc.

Comment: That an excellent solution.  Most of the time I just wanted to point my repository to a disk with enough space on it.  That said, is it (even?) possible to specify a "`settings.xml`" file using `MAVEN_OPTS`?

Comment: M2_HOME used to be need to set the install directory of Maven. This is no longer needed and discouraged. The info in the answer about M2_HOME is completely wrong and the linked doc does NOT indicate what you answered at all. Your solution will NOT change anything regarding the location of the settings file so the answer is effectively wrong.

Comment: This is the best solution, path MUST be absolute though.

Answer (score 14):

The best option is to create the .m2 in your user.home as a symlink upfront before using Maven to point to a local folder on your machine.

Otherwise you could create a shell alias for the mvn called mymvn (or m3 or whatever) that passes in the -s as well as the local repo location.

Comment: Yeah I think this is the best alternative.  Unf I can't create a symlink ( windows :( ) but the alias (in the form of a batch file) will work for the time being.

Comment: [Straightforward, easy way to create symbolic links on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/197273/straightforward-easy-way-to-create-symbolic-links-on-windows)

Comment: @RoyTruelove On windows, maven is being executed from a `.cmd` file (can be opened with notepad), that you can alternatively change to include the `-s` instead of the alias. It is located in `<maven install location>\bin\mvn.cmd`

Answer (score -2):

A bit another use-case, but if you are using Jenkins you can set the `Use private Maven repository` flag and Jenkins will do it for you.

> When this option is checked, Jenkins will tell Maven to use $WORKSPACE/.repository as the local Maven repository. This means each job will get its own isolated Maven repository just for itself.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You need to find your settings.xml file, then edit `<localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>`