# How to package up a leiningen project for recompilation with all the libraries included? [for users without an internet connection]

Tags: maven, clojure, libraries, leiningen

I'm giving a Clojure workshop and I want people to be able to modify and recompile the Clojure project. The challenge is that they won't have internet connections - so I need to give them the project and the libraries all at once.

**How can I package up a leiningen project for recompilation with all the libraries included?**

***Assumptions***

- They have leiningen installed on their machine prior to the workshop.

---

EDIT
This is almost the same question as **How to package up a maven project for recompilation with all the libraries included? [without an internet connection]**

Comment: Would it work to create an uberjar of a project with `lein uberjar` (this contains all non-jvm dependencies and can be run via java -jar) and expect the users to unpack the jar, edit the contents, repack it, and run it? This way they wouldn't need lein, only the tools that come with the jvm.

Comment: Follow up on that suggestion - for java -jar to make a runnable artifact you need :gen-class, and thus you would need recompilation before repackaging, but this could still be the start of a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your ~/.m2 directory aside.  Run all the `lein x` leiningen commands you expect your users to have run, also build and test your project (test, install, jar, uberjar, etc.).  This will have downloaded (a lot) of dependencies for Leiningen itself as well as for your project.  `$HOME/.m2` is where you'll find all the jar files that were pulled down by the Maven dependency resolver.

Once you've done this, add `:offline? true` to the project.clj, According to the documentation, this will [Prevent Leiningen from checking the network for dependencies.](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj)

See [Maven - alternative .m2 directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591080/maven-alternative-m2-directory) for an alternative to having to move your .m2 directory aside.

To make using it easy for your students, it may be best to create a self-contained zip archive with the entire .m2 directory, your project and Leiningen itself, along with a basic installer (bash script, or batch file) that moves or symlinks the .m2 directory into the proper place and adds the lein script to the path.  This approach should satisfy the off-line needs - I think it covers all of the dependencies you would need.

I have assumed that your students will have java installed and have it on their PATH.  Pre-running all of the lein commands you expect to use is important, as some of them have their own dependencies that are only resolved when they are first run.

Comment: Good call, I was just starting to post the same suggestion.

Comment: You'll probably also want to set the `:offline?` key in the sample project.clj that you distribute, to prevent lein for checking for updates (which can still happen e.g. with snapshot dependencies even when Maven has the dependency locally).