# Adding maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to create a basic archetype with maven , for the moment I know how to create the architecture with mvn archetype:generate , however I would like toadd dependencies throughout mvn console.

Is it possibile to add the dependencies from the command line not from the pom file?

I would like to make this because an interesting option is to create  a simple architecture with .bat file.

Comment: check here :https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html

Comment: I am using local and external repository for this example @Roxy

Comment: Wouldn't adding dependencies through command-line instead pom file defeat the whole purpose of repeatable builds?

Comment: what's the use case? I am trying to understand why a `.bat` would suit you better than the `pom.xml` file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I add maven repositories in the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71030/can-i-add-maven-repositories-in-the-command-line)

Comment: The case ,  is to create a bat to generate an automatically structure of the project.

Comment: @jcsa An archetype must have a pre-defined structure, that's the point of using an archetype. If you want to dynamically add dependencies... you'll need to create your own compelete tooling for that, that isn't supported in archetypes -- probably for good reasons: as commented above, this kills any reproducible builds.

Comment: Ah ! , okey I understand now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing out there in the official [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html) at least. The dependencies coming in the generated pom.xml is determined by the archetypeArtifactId option. For example, `-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-j2ee-simple` or `-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp` or any other archetype

## Example

Project generated using `-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp` pom.xml comes only with JUnit dependency